# Need help with pvp commands

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I’m making a map with mini games and within those mini games is pvp. I need help making a command that detects who the last player (winner) is and teleports them to the winners area

Comment: Hi Noah, welcome to Arqade! Could you share some commands that you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: I think one of them was like /testfor @a[x=58,y=94,z=303,r=20,c=2] and that command block was on repeat/unconditional/always active along with a chain command block that teleported the (winner) to the winners area and 58,94,303 is just the xyz of my arena spawn point for all the players. But the problem with that command was that every time there would be one player remaining, that player still wouldn’t get teleported to the winners area

Comment: This was probably asked and answered here before, but I can't find it. What I did find however, was the same question for MCJava, 6 times: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/298078/171580 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/301504/171580 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258501/171580 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/264673/171580 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/214048/171580 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/295599/171580 Maybe an answer on one of those can already help you. If that's the case, please self-answer, so that there is an MCBE answer here as well.